# i want to show that in how many time my thread will run again in c# console application

Tags: c#, console-application

i am working on console application which contain on thread that runs every 5 minute

now all i want to display the time on console application that around this time thread will run again

so user can understand that my program will execute within what ever minutes

```
 getData = new System.Timers.Timer();
            getData.Interval = GetdatascheduleTime; // here 300000 is set 
            getData.Elapsed += objGetDataFromMachin_Elapsed; 
            getData.Enabled = true;
            getData.Start();
```

here is my thread and time that works together and run my `**objGetDataFromMachin_Elapsed**` method on specific time

can any one have solution ?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5).ToString());` ?

Comment: no i want to show time like clock vise means it count like 5,4,3,2,1

Comment: What? I didn't understand the last part...

Comment: How about right after `getData.Start()`, print the `GetdatascheduleTime` out?

Comment: Shorter timer period (1 minute) and counter which is initially set/reset to 5? Print it out every minute until 0 and then run your code and reset.

Comment: A Console App is not a great place to play with Timers and Threads. And you seem to want a countdown. You can do this w/o a Timer. Write a loop that does a Sleep(1000) and compute your progress.

Comment: i want to show live time like e.g like  bom will blast in seconds

Comment: That is called a countdown. You're still not clear about the resolution (minutes or seconds). [Edit] your question, comments don't count here.

Comment: So you probably one *two* timers.  One that start the thread, another that ticks once a second to display the countdown.  It is not clear what else goes on in the program, do not assume your user enjoys watching that grass grow or even cares about a thread.  A service is the more common approach.

Comment: depends if you want a real timer or a fake timer..., real timer will require more code.. which will sync in with the big bang trigger, you will need a while loop of sorts. they are separate so probably different threads